# Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build this simple app, but I always get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined.

```
<template>
  <v-app>

  <div id="example-1">
  <v-btn v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</v-btn>
  <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
</div>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    counter: 0
  }

})

</script>
```

Comment: Have you imported vue anywhere?

Comment: Did you add the cdn for vuejs?

Comment: The error says to you what is wrong. You didn't define Vue anywhere.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, i imported vue in the main.js file : import Vue from 'vue'

Comment: You're missing the important part - how and where you are importing Vue, this isn't a viable question unless you provide that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax with "template" and "v-btn" means that you want to use a vue file.
If it's the case, you have to use something to interpret those files([vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `template` tag with the `div` and add `cdn` at least before `</body>` tag:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div>
  <v-app>
    <div id="example-1">
      <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
       <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script>

var example = new Vue({
    el: '#example-1',
    data: {
      counter: 0
    }
  })

</script>
```

I replaced `v-btn` with the `button` just to show that it works.